# Occurence of double displacement reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

$\ce{AgNO3 + NaCl}$ gives $\ce{NaNO3 + AgCl}$ but why it's vice versa is not possible. My question is how to predict if a double displacement reaction will occur naturally or not.

Comment: Strictly speaking, vice versa is possible, it's just way far from completion. In general, one remembers which compounds posses good solubility and which don't. If in doubt, have a look a their [solubility products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table). Note, however, that solubility (and reactivity) may change drastically by introducing third-party component such as complexing agent or another solvent.

Comment: @andselisk couldn't you possibly write an answer based on this?

Answer (score 0):

On a microscopic level, you still have «a forward» reaction described by

$\ce{AgNO3 + NaCl -> NaNO3 + AgCl}$

and a «backward reaction», which may be described by

$\ce{AgCl + NaNO3 -> AgNO3 + NaCl}$.

*However*, reaching the thermodynamic equilibrium of these two reactions is heavily influenced by the low [solubility product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_equilibrium#Dissolution_with_dissociation) of $\ce{AgCl}$ at about $\sqrt{1.1 \times 10^{-7}}\,\mathrm{mol}$ (or $1.9\,\mathrm{mg}/\mathrm{L}$) in *pure* water at room temperature ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_chloride#Chemistry)).

Consequently, you may either replace the «balanced» double arrow about chemical equilibria

$\ce{AgNO3 + NaCl <=> NaNO3 + AgCl}$

by one tilted in favour to one side

$\ce{AgNO3 + NaCl <=>> NaNO3 + AgCl v}$

where $\ce{v}$ is used to highlight the preciptation of solid $\ce{AgCl}$ shifting the equilibrium.

Or write the reaction equation as *if* there were no microscopic reversibility at all:

$\ce{AgNO3 + NaCl -> NaNO3 + AgCl v}$

---

*Depending* on school and what you want to put emphasis on, the microscopic reversibility often is «omitted» (i.e. the double arrow is dropped in favour of the single arrow) for reactions with a $K > 10^4$ or $K < 10^{-4}$.  On the other hand, you see in many textbooks

$\ce{2 H2O <=> H3O^+ + OH^-}$

despite a $K_w \approx 10^{-14}$, too.